# Why does a commit trigger an access violation?

Tags: sql, delphi, interbase

The following code using the Community version of Delphi and Interbase 2020 running on a Windows 10 machine results in the following error when the Commit is executed. What am I doing wrong?

Project FamilyTree.exe raised exception class $C0000005 with message ‘access violation at 0x00481a6f: read of address 0x8b57569f’.

```
procedure writepreamble;


var

sqltext : string;

basicaction     : tbasicaction;

begin

  sqltext := 'insert into preambleds(preambleseq,text) values(';

  sqltext := sqltext+inttostr(preambleseq)+','+quotedstr(cardimage)+');';

  datamodule1.IBSQL1.SQL.text := sqltext;

  datamodule1.geddb.DefaultTransaction := datamodule1.IBTransaction1;

  datamodule1.IBsql1.Transaction := datamodule1.IBTransaction1;

  datamodule1.IBsql1.Transaction.StartTransaction;

  datamodule1.ibsql1.ExecuteAction(basicaction) ;

  datamodule1.IBsql1.Transaction.Commit;

  sqlcount := sqlcount+1;


end;
```

Comment: `basicaction` doesn't appear to be initialised. Is that intended?

Comment: Go project options, check "Use debug DCUs" and "trace into" the Commit call (if that really is going BEFORE the crash not after) to find the specific line creating AV. Also, don't do things like `sqltext := sqltext+inttostr(preambleseq)` - it is way to easy to screw data types. See https://www.bobby-tables.com and see https://github.com/petdance/bobby-tables/issues/98

Comment: Use the debugger to step through the code to see where the AV occurs. My bet is on `datamodule1.ibsql1.ExecuteAction(basicaction);`, and my bet is that it's becaused you declared `tbasicaction` but never initialized it before using it.

Comment: I don’t know how to set a debug point in a dcu. Is it a module load breakpoint? If so what would the relevant module name be? In addition what are the enumeration types for a basicaction and what might be the relevant action for an insert? Paul Kearney

Comment: For the project, in the compiler options, set "use debug .dcus" to true. Of course you have to use the debug build and run under the debugger (F9).

Comment: Break points can be set pressing F5 when your on a line of code in the editor

Answer (score 0):

why you are using `ExecuteAction` ? 
use `ExecQuery` to execute insert  :

> IBSQL1.ExecQuery();

best regards
Moskw@